# getting error when i reload emulator in react native

Tags: react-native, android-studio

yesterday my application was running very well I closed it when I open my project in vs code and run `npm start` and open an android studio and open emulator I connected it again but this error comes on emulator.[image]

Comment: did you try to run `gradlew clean` inside the android folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your app was made with expo. Instead of `npm start`, use `expo start`. I've had a similar problem where the JavaScript bundle keeps building over and over. I solved it by restarting the app.

If this doesn't work, try restarting your pc.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: how can i restart my app?

Comment: i was working yesterday today I opened my project and getting error in emulator 
"can not connect to metro server"

Comment: Close the whole terminal itself or you can do `ctrl-c` to end the session. Then run `expo start`. This is what I did to fix it

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of `require()` or try restarting your pc.